# Solutions of an integral equation

Tags: integral-equations

Given the integral equation:
$$\sqrt{f(x)}\int_{0}^{x}f(\tau)d\tau=g(x)$$ with g(x) known function,
in what cases and how is it possible to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: If $g(x)=k_1x^\beta$ then the solution has a simple form $f(x)=\sqrt{(\alpha+1)k_1} x^\alpha$ being $\alpha=\frac{2}{3}(\beta-1)$ with $\beta\ne 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square both sides of the equation :
      $$F^'(x) \  (F(x))^2=(g(x))^2$$ 
with $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(\tau)d\tau $.
Now by integration between 0 and t :
$$\frac{(F(t))^3}{3} =  \int_{0}^{t} (g(x))^2 dx$$
F(t) can now be expressed : 
$$F(t) =\sqrt[3]{3} \ \left( \int_{0}^{t} (g(x))^2 dx \right)^{1/3}$$
since $F'(t)=f(t)$, by derivation we obtain : 
$$f(t) = \sqrt[3]{3} \ (g(t))^2 \left(\int_{0}^{t} (g(x))^2 dx \right)^{-2/3}$$

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume that $g(x)$ is differentiable (in fact $g(x)$ should be also positive and monotonously increasing $f(x)$ has to be positive such that the square root is properly defined).

Take a derivative of your equation and you obtain
$$ f(x)^{3/2} + \frac{g(x)\, f'(x)}{2 f(x)} =g'(x). $$
Thus, you have reduced your equation to a differential equation with the initial condition $f(0) = g(0)$.